# Why a command option "-f" be taken as a command by bash

Tags: bash, shell

I run the command copied from the **time**'s manual, but it complained **-f** command not found. Why it recognized **-f** as a command?

```
$ time -f "%E real,%U user,%s sys" ls -Fs
-f: command not found

real    0m0.152s
user    0m0.108s
sys 0m0.040s
```

I doubt the shell and decide to try another shell. In the above, the shell is **bash**. I switched to **dash** and found **time** run correctly now.

My system is Linux Mint 13.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `bash` built-in `command` to suppress shell functions and built-ins:

```
command time -f "%E real,%U user,%s sys" ls -Fs
```

(Longer, but a little more explicit, than using `\time`.)

Answer (score 6):

`time` is a built-in command in `bash` and `zsh`. If you'd like to execute the external command instead, you should call `/usr/bin/time -f ...`.

Answer (score 4):

Bash includes a stripped-down version of `time`. Use `/usr/bin/time` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Added to other answers, you can override the built-in command by `\`.

```
\time -f "%E real,%U user,%s sys" ls -Fs
```